# Data Not inserting to DB - PHP MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Trying to get together the sign up validation with PHP and Ajax. Not sure what is wrong but the submission does not happen. If I don't add the validation part everything looks fine and i am able to insert the data to mysql.

```
<script type="application/javascript">

    $("#submit").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
        console.log(datatopost);
        $.ajax({
            url: "signupregister.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: datatopost,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $("#signupmessage".html(data));
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#signupmessage").html("<div class = 'alert alert-danger'></div>")
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

_

```
<?php    

session_start();
include('mysqlconnection.php');
include('index.php');

function customError($errors, $errorslevel)
{
}

set_error_handler("customError", E_ALL);

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($_POST($first_name) == "") {
        $errors .= $first_nameError;
    } else {
        $first_name =
            filter_var($_POST["first_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
}


if ($errors) {
    $resultMessage = '<div class="alert alert-danger">' .
        $errors . '</div>';
    echo $resultMessage;
    exit;
}
$first_nameError = '<p>first name required</p>';
```

Comment: Posted PHP insert code now. i have only included first name but there are many other fields.

Comment: update the question with any nrew code (dont post it as a comment) and are you saying its s js\ajax issue or a php one?

Comment: i am actually unsure where the issue is. log file does not give me any error either. Also , i am not able to show the error message above the sign up box.

Comment: Your code is a mess. I'd work on formatting (indentation for starters). This will make it easier to maintain your own code and easier for us to make sense of it. Another specific point, don't through javascript and PHP at us like it was in the same file. Or maybe that is your issue and you forgot your `<?php` tags? Grr. I stopped and cleaned it up...

Comment: its easy to check if the php is actually being hit and what is being posted to it, that will narrow down the issue. (f12 - browser developer tools, network tab)

Comment: I m sorry- i did not intend to copy the code in a unlined fashion. but the tool was asking to produce some space for the code to be posted. hence i tabbed the space which messed up the code lines.

Comment: This is error message i get - using chrome:                                 
 Input elements should have autocomplete attributes (suggested: autocomplete='given-name', <input type=​"text" name=​"first_name" placeholder=​"First Name*">​

Comment: There's no insertion code here, just something that filters variables.

Answer (score 0):

First up, in your validation PHP script, you won't need to include 'index.php'

Try redirecting the form to an empty page where you only include your validation data, while setting a session variable for the first error encountered.

At the end of your validation, if your error variable contains an error, you can redirect to the form and display your said error at a convenient location. Keep in mind you will have to save form data in session variables if you want to preserve all user input (thus removing the hassle of refilling the form over and over again).
If it doesn't, you can proceed to insert the data in your db then redirect to your desired landing page.

Here's a sample code based on your input:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname'];
        //so on for your other variables
        if($_SESSION['fname'] == ""){
            $_SESSION['err'] = "First Name Required";
        }
        if(//insert your format validation for first name){
             $_SESSION['err'] = "First Name Invalid";}
        }
        //end of validation
        if isset($_SESSION['err']){
           header('Location: myform.php');
        }
        else{
            //save all your variables into normal ones, i.e $fname-$_POST['fname'];
           //insert into database;
           //check correct insertion;
           //redirect to landing page;
}
}
?>
```